# Conditionally return actions in NgRx effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to check a condition in the effect and dispatch different actions based on the condition result. The conditional parameters are obtained from Store and a API call like below.

```
@Effect()
// error here - Observable<void> is not assignable to type Observable<Action>
  loadUserSkills$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActionTypes.REQUEST_USER_SKILLS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .map(([action, storeState]) => {
      this.skillsService.getUserSkillsCacheVersion().
        map((cacheVersion) => {
          if (cacheVersion === storeState.users.cacheVersion.userSkills) {
            return new UsersActions.RequestUserSkillsFromStore();
          } else {
            return new UsersActions.RequestUserSkillsFromServer();
          }
        });
      });
```

What's not correct here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by modifiying the effect slightly and ForkJoined the observable like below.

```
  @Effect()
  loadUserSkills$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActionTypes.REQUEST_USER_SKILLS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .map(([, storeState]) => storeState.users.cacheVersion.userSkills)
    .switchMap((currentCacheVersion) =>
      forkJoin([of(currentCacheVersion), this.skillsService.getUserSkillsCacheVersion()]))
    .map((data: any) => {
      const [currentCacheVersion, latestCacheVersion] = data;
      if (latestCacheVersion !== 0 && currentCacheVersion === latestCacheVersion) {
        return new UsersActions.RequestUserSkillsFromStore();
      } else {
        return new UsersActions.RequestUserSkillsFromServer();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning inside your map.

```
return this.skillsService...
```

So typescript thinks it's a void

Answer (score 0):

I would try this without declaring a type for the loadUserSkills$  I've never seen anyone declare the type there.  Also new standard is not to dot chain but to use.

```
    this.actons$.pipe(ofType(...),withLatestFrom(...),...
```

Did you include your store in the constructor of the class?

```
    constructor(private store$: AppState, private actions$: Action)
```

also typically you would use a selector to select pieces of state in your effects, not directly access them like that. Look into NGRX selectors.

```
    this.store$.pipe(select(selectUserSkills))
```

but you would have to setup a selector called selectUserSkills

Also if your this.skillsService.getUserSkillsCacheVersion() is returning an Observable you need to subscribe to it for anything to happen.

I think more info is needed here. Please post more code. Is this error occurring during run time or compile time?